# stargazer with R table output or for "special" summary statistics

Tags: r, stargazer

I have a categorical variable, df$Chain, taking on levels 1,2,3 and 4. I have a variable, df$State, taking on levels 0, 1. I would like to produce a table that shows proportions by state. The standard deviation of the proportions and the t-statistic of a test of equality of the two proportions.

I can produce the proportions via

```
table.1 <- prop.table(table(dfLong$CHAIN,dfLong$STATE), margin = 2)
```

which gives

```
            0         1
  1 0.4430380 0.4108761
  2 0.1518987 0.2054381
  3 0.2151899 0.2477341
  4 0.1898734 0.1359517
```

and goes into the right direction.

But, when I give this object to stargazer via

```
stargazer(table.1, type = 'text')
```

it stacks the proportions to

```
  0 1  NA  
 -----------
 1 1 0 0.443
 2 2 0 0.152
 3 3 0 0.215
 4 4 0 0.190
 5 1 1 0.411
 6 2 1 0.205
 7 3 1 0.248
 8 4 1 0.136
 -----------
```

How can I get the proportions within a state next to each other and add standard errors and t-statistics?

Is stargazer the right tool for this at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your data and `prop.table` is

```
set.seed(123)
dfLong <- data.frame(CHAIN = sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     STATE = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))
table.1 <- prop.table(table(dfLong$CHAIN,dfLong$STATE), margin = 2)
```

The idea is to define `class` for `table.1` as `matrix` and instruct `stargazer` to print out the matrix "as is":

```
class(table.1) <- "matrix"
stargazer(table.1, type = "text", summary = FALSE)
# =============
#     0     1  
# -------------
# 1 0.180 0.340
# 2 0.320 0.220
# 3 0.220 0.180
# 4 0.280 0.260
# -------------
```

Using this approach you can `cbind` other quantities of interest (standard errors, etc.) to the original matrix, and run the augmented matrix through `stargazer`.

Comment: Hi, many thanks. Is Stargazer generally the right tool for this? I am actually trying to find produce something like table 2 (page 776) in this famous paper: http://davidcard.berkeley.edu/papers/njmin-aer.pdf
For instance, with your solution it would be difficult to get the s.e. in parantheses beneath the averages, correct?

Comment: It's possible to do that with `stargazer`.  But if that's your actual question, I'd suggest you open a new question and be specific about the layout that you have in mind.

Comment: @cyrus-mohammadian, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @clog stargazer spits out tables in html, latex, among other formats. You mentioned you want a table to look like the one in that paper your posted. Well that was created using LaTeX.

Comment: @WeihuangWong, many thanks. I followed your advice and posted a more comprehensive question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439293/complex-summary-tables-with-stargazer-reproducing-table-2-from-card-and-krueger
Thanks for your help so far, really appreciate it.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, yes I am aware that that table was not produced with stargazer. I guess my question is how far one can go with stargazer in producing tables like that. I am actually not interested in a latex table, but in an html table. I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439293/complex-summary-tables-with-stargazer-reproducing-table-2-from-card-and-krueger

Comment: @clog14 see https://gist.github.com/weihuangwong/d458a5399b6219e607d5f49a08efe1ce for an example.  I used the built in `iris` dataset, but you should be able to adapt the code to your purposes.